# Python CSV headers are not writing correctly

Tags: python, csv

I would like to write two headers, but am receving my actual two headers and 3 blank fields.  What could be the cause of this? Here is my script and output.  The script parses a JSON web-service and sends lat/lng of buses to an Esri file geodatabase.

[image]

[image]

```
import requests
import json
import urllib2
import csv
import arcpy





if arcpy.Exists("C:\MYLATesting.gdb\API_Table"):
    arcpy.Delete_management("C:\MYLATesting.gdb\API_Table")

url = "http://api.metro.net/agencies/lametro/vehicles/"
parsed_json = json.load(urllib2.urlopen("http://api.metro.net/agencies/lametro/vehicles/"))
details = {'items': 'longitude'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': '/'}
response = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(details), headers=headers)


# tell computer where to put CSV
outfile_path='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API_Testing.csv'

# open it up, the w means we will write to it
writer = csv.writer(open(outfile_path, 'wb'))

#create a list with headings for our columns
headers = ['latitude','longitude']

for items in parsed_json['items']:
    row = []
    row.append(str(items['latitude']).encode('utf-8'))
    row.append(str(items['longitude']).encode('utf-8'))
    writer.writerow(row)

i = 1
i = i +1

f = open(outfile_path, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f)
#write the row of headings to our CSV file
writer.writerow(headers)

f.close()

#Temporary Delete Function to Overwrite Table

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(outfile_path, "C:\MYLATesting.gdb", "API_Table")

print response.text
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra blank columns could mean one of two things:
1. you're script is outputting additional commas (,) at the end of each line, which your spreadsheet program interprets as additional columns OR
2. The TableToTable_conversion function is doing something funky to what appears to be a database schema.

Are you viewing the cvs through a database suite? Post a screenshot of what it looks like in Notepad

Comment: I don't think that it's my TabletoTable_Conversion as the function takes the fields from the csv.